# Can't place a figure in the right place

Tags: floats

I keep trying to code a figure so it goes after the example and function but it keeps either going to the top of the page or going above the example or below the definition. Is there anyway to stop this happening or alternative code that would work?

```
begin{defn}
A function $f:A \rightarrow B$ is \textbf{One-to-One} if there exists $c_{1},c_{2} \in A$ with $f(c_{1})=f(c_{2})$ such that $c_{1}=c_{2}$\cite{lecture}. Therefore for every element $x$ in A there is a unique element $f(x)$in B it maps to. \par  
\end{defn}
\begin{exmp} [Equation $f(x)=x^{2}, A = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} | x \geq 0\} $]
\vfill
\afterpage{\FloatBarrier}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{one-to-one}
\end{figure}[h]
\vfill
\afterpage{\FloatBarrier}
    \end{exmp}
```

Comment: Well, remove the `figure` environment if you don't want to let it float away

Comment: it is impossible to run your fragment but I would start by removing `\vfill
\afterpage{\FloatBarrier}` which (might) possibly be useful in some special circumstances but is very fragile and invasive command to use in a normal document, then as Christian said, the only reason to use `figure` is to allow latex to move that text so if you don't want it to move you do not need `figure`

Comment: FWIW, the definition of one-to-one function is completely wrong.